# Sorting columns in table with 2 th level using JQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an HTML table looking like this

[image]

I want to be able to sort the columns inside the table, but only inside the th above.

For example, only A-1, A-2 and A-3 can go below A, in any possible order.

I initialize the sorting using JQueryUI and this code

```
$("table thead tr:last").sortable({
    axis: 'X',
    containment: 'parent',
    items: " > th",
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zirkonix/uca9940v/1/)

I've tried so far to group the second line of th inside wrappers and use this wrapper as a containment div.

```
<tr>
    <dragWrapper>
        <th>A-1</th>
        <th>A-2</th>
        <th>A-3</th>
    </dragWrapper>
    <dragWrapper>
        <th>B-1</th>
        <th>B-2</th>
    </dragWrapper>
    <dragWrapper>
        <th>C-1</th>
        <th>C-2</th>
    </dragWrapper>
</tr>
```

It actually worked, but it completely destroyed the table layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmblackwood/uca9940v/6/

Here's a few things:

You can't define custom HTML elements. For example `<dragWrapper>` is not going to be interpreted by the browser (unless you're using some compiler/language you haven't mentioned in the question).

What I've done is rebuilt your table structure so that each of your letter-ID blocks is its own table.

You were also using a selector in your jQuery method `tr:last`, which should have been `tr:last-child`.